# How to stop capturing Keyboard event until current keyboard event finish?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm having problem with keyboard event when pressing the key before last keyboard event finish being executed. Here I have a onKeyPressed event:

```
keyBoardListener->onKeyPressed = 
[&](cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keycode, Event* event){
    switch (keycode)
      case cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:
      // Move 900 pixel to the Right in 3s
      case cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:
      // Jump.
};
```

Lets say my character is now at position x When I press KEY_RIGHT_ARROW, my chracter start moving 900 pixel to the right in **3 seconds**. However, **1 second after** that I press KEY_UP_ARROW. Now I **expect** that my character keep moving until he reaches the goal (x + 900) then jump, but **in fact** he jumps right where he was when I press KEY_UP_ARROW.

The 2 solutions come out of my mind is that I need to somehow prevent my app from capturing any new Keyboard event until the current event finish or save them somewhere and execute them later in a First In First Out sequence . So:

1/ Is that a good way to deal with it? If so then how to do it ?

2/ Are there any other solutions ?

Your help is very much appreciated.

**Update** : I tried to set a flag to prevent new keyboard event but It still the same:

```
int flag = 0;
keyBoardListener->onKeyPressed = 
[&](cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keycode, Event* event){
    if(flag==0)
    {
       flag++;
          switch (keycode)
             case cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:
             // Move 900 pixel to the Right in 3s
             case cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:
              // Jump.
       flag--;
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand where's your problem exactly. If you have some animation running when right arrow is pressed you can remember in vector all clicks. If, by chance, your action is, for example, moving character to the right you can just set a flag, which knows if the character is running right, then in update function you can move it by a bit (speed * delta).

Comment: @Makalele Sorry for the poor explanation. My problem is that, lets say my character is now at position x When I press KEY_RIGHT_ARROW, my character start moving 900 pixel to the right in 3 seconds. However, 1 second after that I press KEY_UP_ARROW. Now I expect that my character keep moving until he reaches the goal (x + 900.f) then jump, but in fact he jumps right where he was when I press KEY_UP_ARROW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine, the simplest way to do this, is to store actions in a vector, like this:

in .h file:

```
virtual void update(float delta) override;
Vector<ActionInterval* > actions;
```

then in .cpp file:

```
keyBoardListener->onKeyPressed = 
[&](cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode keycode, Event* event){

   switch (keycode)
      case cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:
            // Move 900 pixel to the Right in 3s
            auto newAction = MoveBy::create(3.0f, Vec2(900, 0));
            newAction->setTag(101);
            actions.pushBack(newAction);

      case cocos2d::EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:
              // Jump.
            auto newAction = MoveBy::create(3.0f, Vec2(0, 500));
            newAction->setTag(101);
            actions.pushBack(newAction);

};

scheduleUpdate();

void MyScene::update(float delta){
    if(sprite->getActionByTag(101) == nullptr){ //idle
        if(actions.size() > 0){ //get oldest action
            auto action = actions.at(0);
            actions.erase(0); //remove it from vector
            sprite->runAction(action); //play it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your idea and I'll try it out. However, I think it's good as long as I only use Action. However, in my case, I need to do other stuff after running the Action likes `sprite->setPosition()`,  `sprite->setOpacity()`, `sprite->setEnabled()` or so. So how to make the next event wait till all of those processes finish?

Comment: You can store single commands in CallFunc and add it to actions as well.